# Select data that wont expire in the next 60 days

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to select data that won't expire in the **next 60** days so far I have this

```
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM cooler WHERE expiry_date > CURDATE()";
```

which only shows data that has not expire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add 60 days to the `CURDATE()` with `DATE_ADD` and an `INTERVAL` of `+60 DAY`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM cooler WHERE expiry_date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +60 DAY)";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql="Select id FROM cooler WHERE expiry_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 60 DAY";
```